# Remove the HTML from renderField output

Tags: joomla, strip-tags

Is there any way I could strip html out of this?

```
<?php echo $this->form->renderField('monday'); ?>
```

In the back end theres a selection where you pick options that show up in a schedule but they are showing up as html and I need them to show up as plain text for the selection.

Comment: A quick google search for "php strip html tags" returned [PHP strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). It's good to search around and try to answer the question yourself. After you are truly stuck stackoverflow is your friend :)

Comment: Ive been searching for a way to fix it for 2 days with hardly any sleep lol nothings working so far. Im starting to think it cant be fixed. I tried the snippet from the one answer and the code didn't work, it broke the field so nothing at all can be selected (just text showed up where the selection should appear) so it looks like I'm looking in the wrong place to apply the solution :S

Answer (score 0):

you can use php strip_tags function

```
<?php echo strip_tags($this->form->renderField('monday')); ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php.

If you wanna keep some tags, look at the section allowable_tags

Answer (score 0):

You should know that select and option are also html tags and will be removed if you use strip_tags. So you can allow those tags. You can modify your code like this

```
<?php $field = strip_tags(($this->form->renderField('monday')),'<select><option>'); 
      echo $field;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried your code and it didn't break the selection but the items in the selection are still showing up as code. Im thinking that this particular place in the code I originally thought, is the wrong place for me to try and strip the tags out.